# Easy way to get the touch point on the x-axis, Cocoa Touch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, touch, uistoryboard

It seems like this should be simple, but it is apparently not so.

I am using Storyboards, with my first view controller defined as `LogbookFirstViewController`.

The contents of this controller are inside of a `UIControl`. That way I can detect taps.

However, I can see no easy way to determine when a user has started swiping across the screen. All I want to do is get the touches x-coordinate. Essentially track it.

I dropped a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` inside `LogbookFirstViewController`, and attached it's outlet too:

In `.h`

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer;
```

Of course, I then synthesized it and set the delegate:

In `.m`

```
[gestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *touchLoc = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint beginCenter = self.view.center;
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touchLoc locationInView:self.view];

    deltaX = touchPoint.x - beginCenter.x;
    deltaY = touchPoint.y - beginCenter.y;
    NSLog(@"X = %f & Y = %f", deltaX, deltaY);
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    // Set the correct center when touched
    touchPoint.x -= deltaX;
    touchPoint.y -= deltaY;

    self.view.center = touchPoint;
}
```

However, this does nothing. It doesn't even detect `-(void)touchesBegan`

What am I missing? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those methods are not delegate methods, they're only for subclassing `UIGestureRecognizer`.

Typically you instantiate a gesture recognizer and specify a selector (a method) to call when that gesture is recognized and then you assign it to a view, for example:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pan:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:pan]
```

Then in your `pan` method you can query information from teh gesture:

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    // get information from the gesture object
}
```

I've never done it with a StoryBoard but I suppose if you have a property already in your view controller you could call `addTarget:action:` and attach it to a view in the view controllers `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now, what information can I use to get the current finger location with this? What I used above? Something else?

Comment: Yep, the `UIGestureRecognizer` class has the methods: `– locationInView:` and `– locationOfTouch:inView:` that you can use inside that `pan:` method above.